# How to populate checkbox dynamically in php?

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to populate checkbox dynamically for which i get the values from database and stored in checkbox but values are not shown how i show the values.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <?
    //echo $eventid=$_POST['events'];
    $count=count($_POST['events']);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $select="select b.first_name,b.last_name from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' group by r.buyer_id";
        $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);
        if ($res->num_rows > 0)
        {           
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc ())
            {
            ?>  
                <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<? echo $row['first_name'];$row['last_name']?>"/><br />              
            <?
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: value="<? echo $row['first_name'];$row['last_name']?>"/ - what format do you want? If there is no error, then only $row['first_name'] will be displayed by the echo.

Comment: i want to show checkbox with $row['first_name'] value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your value attribute of checkbox should be

`value="<?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?>"`

try this

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?>"/><br />
```

instead of

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<? echo $row['first_name'];$row['last_name']?>"/><br />
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?>"/> 
 <?php echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?> <br />
```

Comment: i used your code but only checked chekbox shown values not shown with checkbox

Answer (score 0):

As of your comment (you want to set the first name as the value):

```
$select="select b.first_name,b.last_name from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' group by r.buyer_id";
```

Change

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<? echo $row['first_name'];$row['last_name']?>"/><br />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $row['first_name'];?>"/><br />
```

And (because you're selecting from two tables), you should use AS in your query like:

```
$select="select b.first_name AS first_name,b.last_name AS last_name from buyers b,registrations r where b.buyer_id=r.buyer_id and r.event_id='".$_POST['events'][$i]."' group by r.buyer_id";
```

(maybe not necessary)

Also take a look at [prepared statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent SQL-Injections.

Answer (score -1):

Give Value like this

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts" checked="checked" value="<?php echo $row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?>"/><br />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<div>
    <?php /* <-- Don't use PHP short tags, it's a bad practice, they are deprecated */

        /* Making select statement inside a loop is a very bad idea. 
           Also, you should make sure to properly escape
           $_POST['events']), as inserting unescaped inputs into a query 
           is very unsafe   */

        $post = array_map(
            array($GLOBALS['mysqli'], "escape_string"), 
            $_POST['events']
        );

         /* We apply mysqli::escape_string to every element of 
            $_POST['events'] and save result as $post */

        $select = "SELECT `b`.`first_name`, `b`.`last_name` FROM `buyers` `b` ".
                  "JOIN `registrations`.`r` ON `r`.`buyer_id` = `b`.`buyer_id` ".
                  "WHERE `r`.`event_id` IN ('".implode("','", $post)."') ".
                  "GROUP BY `r`.`buyer_id`";
        $res = $GLOBALS ['mysqli']->query ($select) 
               or die ($GLOBALS ['mysqli']->error . __LINE__);

        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
           <label>
               <input type="checkbox" name="receptionts[]" checked="checked" value="<?= $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name']?>"/> 
               <?= $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'] ?>
           </label>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
```